# Merging 2 sed commands into 1

Tags: sed

Is there a way to do the following in a single `sed` command to improve performance?

```
cat some_file | sed -n '/^MODIFIED/p' | sed 's/^MODIFIED\s*//g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below sed command. `-n` and `p` helps to print those lines where the replacement takesplace. `[[:space:]]*` POSIX notation which matches zero or more spaces.

```
sed -n 's/^MODIFIED[[:space:]]*//p' some_file
```

OR

```
sed -n 's/^MODIFIED\s*//p' some_file
```

Example:

```
$ cat ri
MODIFIED  foo bar
apple
mango
$ cat ri | sed -n '/^MODIFIED/p' | sed 's/^MODIFIED\s*//g'
foo bar
$ sed -n 's/^MODIFIED[[:space:]]*//p' ri
foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove both cat and sed, just use last sed like:

```
sed -nr 's/^MODIFIED\s*//p' some_file
```

Comment: Not sure this is the same.  First `sed` prints only line starting with `MODIFIED`, then second `sed` remove this text.  You `sed` prints all line.

Comment: cat will read the file and display all the lines. next sed reads a line and searches every line that starts with MODIFIED and print those lines while third sed replaces every line that starts with MODIFIED followed by say space or tabs and removed them and that's what final sed does.

Comment: May i know the reason for downvote please? I have this file  MODIFIED,10  MODIFIED1,20 and when i run the command it returns me   ,10

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk 'gsub(/^MODIFIED\s*/,"")' file
```

Example:

```
cat file
test
MODIFIED data
more MODIFIED home
```

```
awk 'gsub(/^MODIFIED\s*/,"")' file
data
```